# Count the number of unique values per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have 2 columns - _a, _b.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'_a':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3],'_b':[3,4,5,3,3,3,9], 'a_b_3':[3,3,3,1,1,2,2]})
df

    _a  _b  a_b_3   
0   1   3   3
1   1   4   3
2   1   5   3
3   2   3   1
4   2   3   1
5   3   3   2
6   3   9   2
```

I need create column a_b_3 (unique count from column '_b') use groupby from pandas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: it's not clear what you want. can you explain a bit more?

Comment: For example, in column 'a_b_3' count unique column '_b' = 3, because  if column '_a'=1 then unique values column '_b'  is [3,4,5]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want `transform` + `nunique`;

```
df['a_b_3'] = df.groupby('_a')['_b'].transform('nunique')        
df
   _a  _b  a_b_3
0   1   3      3
1   1   4      3
2   1   5      3
3   2   3      1
4   2   3      1
5   3   3      2
6   3   9      2
```

This is effectively `groupby` + `nunique` + `map`:

```
v = df.groupby('_a')['_b'].nunique()
df['a_b_3'] = df['_a'].map(v)

df
   _a  _b  a_b_3
0   1   3      3
1   1   4      3
2   1   5      3
3   2   3      1
4   2   3      1
5   3   3      2
6   3   9      2
```

Comment: I was about to do the `map` part :(

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan Apologies, you kinda dropped the ball with merge, but your heart's in the right place so I've upvoted your answer :)

Comment: I knew this could be done with a transform I just couldn't figure it out! Nice!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Use -

```
df2=df.groupby(['_a'])['_b'].nunique().reset_index()
df['a_b_3'] = df.merge(df2, how='left', on='_a')[['_b_y']]
```

**Output**

```
   _a  _b  a_b_3
0   1   3      3
1   1   4      3
2   1   5      3
3   2   3      1
4   2   3      1
5   3   3      2
6   3   9      2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly what you want is to group by column _a, count the number of unique values in column _b within each group and then append this count to the original dataframe using _a as the key. The following code should achieve that.

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('_a')._b.nunique()), left_on='_a', right_index=True)
```

Breaking it down, the first thing is to group by _a and then count the uniques in column _b. That's what `df.groupby('_a')._b.nunique()` does. Then it's merged with the original dataframe using _a as the key. The groupby returns a series so we need to convert it to a dataframe before merging, hence the `pd.DataFrame`.

EDIT

@COLDSPEED's answer above is much more efficient than this one. To give an idea of the speed difference I ran a timeit which shows a speed up of 2x on this small dataframe, on larger dataframes it would probably be even more.

Using merge:

```
%timeit df.merge(pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('_a')._b.nunique()), left_on='_a', right_index=True)
1.43 ms ± 74.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Using transform:

```
%timeit df.groupby('_a')['_b'].transform('nunique')
750 µs ± 32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is effectively https://stackoverflow.com/a/50268881/4909087 on a single line. However I would _not_ recommend a merge as it isn't nearly as fast as you can actually get in terms of solving this problem.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't see that had been posted and agree that transform is much nicer. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: No worries, keep it. It isn't a problem. I've passed you an upvote, please keep contributing to the tag!

Comment: Thanks, I've added some timing so my answer at least provides a little bit of value!